# Can't install libgl1-mesa-dri 32bit

Tags: apt

When I run the command sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri I get this:

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libllvm8:i386 (>= 1:8~svn298832-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libsensors4:i386 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 did this...

````
  gcc-4.7-base:i386{a} libbsd0:i386{ab} libc6:i386{ab} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{ab} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{ab}
  libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} libdrm2:i386{ab} libedit2:i386{ab} libelf1:i386{ab} libexpat1:i386{ab} libffi6:i386{ab}
  libgcc1:i386{ab} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{b} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libllvm8:i386{ab} libpciaccess0:i386{ab}
  libsensors4:i386{ab} libtinfo5:i386{ab} zlib1g:i386{ab}
0 packages upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 283 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-nouveau2 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (!= 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2 (!= 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b) but 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 libllvm8:i386 : Depends: libatomic1:i386 (>= 4.8) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libtinfo5:i386 (>= 6) but 5.9-10ubuntu4 is to be installed
                 Breaks: libllvm8 (!= 1:8.0.1~+rc3-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b) but 1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
 libllvm8 : Breaks: libllvm8:i386 (!= 1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1) but 1:8.0.1~+rc3-1ubuntu1~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libpciaccess0 : Breaks: libpciaccess0:i386 (!= 0.14-1) but 0.13.1-2 is to be installed
 libpciaccess0:i386 : Breaks: libpciaccess0 (!= 0.13.1-2) but 0.14-1 is installed
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2) but 19.2~git1908020730.54fbc6~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 19.2~git1908020730.54fbc6~oibaf~b) but 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 is installed
 libelf1 : Breaks: libelf1:i386 (!= 0.170-0.4ubuntu0.1) but 0.153-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libelf1:i386 : Breaks: libelf1 (!= 0.153-2ubuntu1) but 0.170-0.4ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libbsd0 : Breaks: libbsd0:i386 (!= 0.8.7-1) but 0.4.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libbsd0:i386 : Breaks: libbsd0 (!= 0.4.2-1ubuntu1) but 0.8.7-1 is installed
 zlib1g : Breaks: zlib1g:i386 (!= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Breaks: zlib1g (!= 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libexpat1 : Breaks: libexpat1:i386 (!= 2.2.5-3ubuntu0.1) but 2.1.0-2 is to be installed
 libexpat1:i386 : Breaks: libexpat1 (!= 2.1.0-2) but 2.2.5-3ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc1 (!= 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1) but 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1 (!= 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b) but 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (!= 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libtinfo5 : Breaks: libtinfo5:i386 (!= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 5.9-10ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libtinfo5:i386 : Breaks: libtinfo5 (!= 5.9-10ubuntu4) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is installed
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b) but 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2) but 19.2~git1908020730.54fbc6~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 19.2~git1908020730.54fbc6~oibaf~b) but 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 is installed
 libedit2 : Breaks: libedit2:i386 (!= 3.1-20170329-1) but 2.11-20080614-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libedit2:i386 : Breaks: libedit2 (!= 2.11-20080614-5ubuntu1) but 3.1-20170329-1 is installed
 libffi6 : Breaks: libffi6:i386 (!= 3.2.1-8) but 3.0.13-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libffi6:i386 : Breaks: libffi6 (!= 3.0.13-2ubuntu1) but 3.2.1-8 is installed
 libdrm-radeon1 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b is to be installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.99+git1907300630.6652cf~oibaf~b) but 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 libsensors4 : Breaks: libsensors4:i386 (!= 1:3.4.0-4) but 1:3.3.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libsensors4:i386 : Breaks: libsensors4 (!= 1:3.3.2-2ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.0-4 is installed```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I made a clean new installation, did dpkg add-architecture i386 and when I run apt update I get this:

```
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease 
[88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease 
[88.7 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease 
[74.6 kB]
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 
Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386  
Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 
Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 
Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 
Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 
Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 
Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 
Packages
 Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Err:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Err:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main armhf Packages [674 kB]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages

Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Err:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Fetched 252 kB in 15s (16.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```